# Update MySQL table any time another table changes

Tags: mysql, triggers, database-trigger, mysql-5.7

I am trying to reduce the number of queries my application uses to build the dashboard and so am trying to gather all the info I will need in advance into one table. Most of the dashboard can be built in javascript using the JSON which will reduce server load doing tons of PHP foreach, which was resulting in excess queries.

With that in mind, I have a query that pulls together user information from 3 other tables, concatenates the results in JSON group by family. I need to update the JSON object any time anything changes in any of the 3 tables, but not sure what the "right " way to do this is.

I could set up a regular job to do an UPDATE statement where date is newer than the last update, but that would miss new records, and if I do inserts it misses updates. I could drop and rebuild the table, but it takes about 16 seconds to run the query as a whole, so that doesn't seem like the right answer.

Here is my initial query:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 100000;
SELECT family_id, REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONCAT("[", GROUP_CONCAT(family), "]"), "\\", ""), '"[', '['), ']"', ']') as family_members
FROM (

SELECT family_id,
    JSON_OBJECT(
"customer_id",                      c.id, 
"family_id",                        c.family_id,
"first_name",                       first_name,
"last_name",                        last_name,
"balance_0_30",                     pa.balance_0_30,
"balance_31_60",                    pa.balance_31_60,
"balance_61_90",                    pa.balance_61_90,
"balance_over_90",                  pa.balance_over_90,
"account_balance",                  pa.account_balance,
"lifetime_value",                   pa.lifetime_value,
"orders",                           CONCAT("[", past_orders, "]")
) AS family

FROM
    customers AS c
LEFT JOIN accounting AS pa ON c.id = pa.customer_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT patient_id, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            JSON_OBJECT(
            "id",                   id,
            "item",                 item,
            "price",                price,
            "date_ordered",         date_ordered
            )
        ) as past_orders 
    FROM orders
    WHERE date_ordered < NOW()
    GROUP BY customer_id
) AS r ON r.customer_id = c.id
where c.user_id = 1

) AS results
GROUP BY family_id
```

I briefly looked into triggers, but what I was hoping for was something like:

```
create TRIGGER UPDATE_FROM_ORDERS
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
ON orders
(EXECUTE QUERY FROM ABOVE WHERE family_id = orders.family_id)
```

I was hoping to create something like that for each table, but at first glance it doesn't look like you can run complex queries such as that where we are creating nested JSON.

Am I wrong? Are triggers the right way to do this, or is there a better way?

Comment: A MySQL TRIGGER is prohibited from returning a resultset, that is, running a bare SELECT that returns rows.  A MySQL trigger can be either (one of) `BEFORE` or `AFTER`  and (one of) `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE`.  If we want to trigger "after insert" and "after update" we'd need two triggers. (Complex logic can be incorporated into a procedure which is called from a trigger (shared by multiple triggers.) Values of columns from the current row can be referenced via OLD or NEW, for example `NEW.family_id`. (I'm not aware of a restriction on using JSON_OBJECT function in a trigger, there might b

Comment: But I need it to find the family_id, return all customers, go search orders, group them in JSON and so on anytime something changes. Can that be done with a trigger, or does it all need to be done in something like PHP task?

Comment: A trigger can not "return" a result set. A trigger can run SQL statements, with some restrictions (e.g. a trigger can't modify any rows in the table fired the trigger.) A BEFORE trigger can modify values being assigned to columns in the current row. A trigger can run SQL statements against other tables. SELECT statements within a trigger can return values into local variables or user-defined variables. (It's not clear what the objective is...  if the goal is to return a resultset from a bare SELECT, then it's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a demonstration:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER orders_au
ON orders
AFTER UPDATE
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET group_concat_max_len = 100000
   ;
   UPDATE target_table t
      SET t.somecol = ( SELECT expr 
                          FROM ...
                         WHERE somecol = NEW.family_id
                         ORDER BY ...
                         LIMIT 1
                      )
    WHERE t.family_id = NEW.family_id
   ;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

---

Notes:

MySQL triggers are row level triggers; a trigger is fired for "for each row" that is affected by the triggering statement. MySQL does not support statement level triggers.

The reference to `NEW.family_id` is a reference to the value of the `family_id` column of the row that was just updated, the row that the trigger was fired for.

MySQL trigger prohibits the SQL statements in the trigger from modifying any rows in the `orders` table. But it can modify other tables.

SQL statements in a trigger body can be arbitrarily complex, as long as its not a bare SELECT returning a resultset, or DML INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements. DDL statements (most if not all) are disallowed in a MySQL trigger.

Comment: Thank you, that is I think what I am trying to do, take the info from orders and update the `dashboard` table

Comment: I suggest you experiment/test/exercise with triggers using simpler (trivial) SQL to generate a payload. Once you get the trigger working, then extend the SQL to include the GROUP_CONCAT, JSON_OBJECT, etc. to see if any SQL restrictions pop up. (Don't fight two dragons at the same time, get the TRIGGER beast tamed first. Then wrestle with getting the trigger to do what you need.)

Comment: I think I totally avoided the question as to whether doing "this" in a trigger is "the right way to do this", mostly because it wasn't clear to me what "this" (what we are attempting to do) was. Having an understanding of triggers, how they operate and the restrictions should help you determine if they are appropriate for your use case.